# blackberry httpconnection issue in edge network

Tags: java, blackberry, inputstream, httpconnection

I am facing problem in getting data in blackberry application.Below code i use to get the data from a server which is in xml format and i parse this data and show it to the user.It works fine in wi-fi but when i run it on real device using EDGE or GPRSit works very slow and lot of times it gives inputstream null.I am not getting why this is happening in slow network but not in wi-fi.

```
public InputStream getInputStream(String url)
{   
    HttpConnection  httpConnection = null;
    try
    {
        httpConnection = getConnectionForRequest(url);
        final int iResponseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(iResponseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            return httpConnection.openInputStream();

        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
            finally
            {
                if(httpConnection!=null)
                {
                      httpConnection.close();
                }
            }

}

public HttpConnection getConnectionForRequest(String url) 
{

    int[] availableTransportTypes = {TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI,
                                     TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, 
                                     TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2,
                                     TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR, 
                                     TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS, 
                                     TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP};
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();


    for (int i = 0; i < availableTransportTypes.length; i++) 
    {
        int transport = availableTransportTypes[i];
        if (!TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(transport) || !TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(transport)) 
        {
            Arrays.removeAt(availableTransportTypes, i);
        }
    }

    connectionFactory.setPreferredTransportTypes(availableTransportTypes);
    connectionFactory.setAttemptsLimit(50);
    connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(3000);
    connectionFactory.setTimeLimit(20000);
    final ConnectionDescriptor connectionDescriptor = connectionFactory.getConnection(url);
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    if (connectionDescriptor != null) 
    {
        connection = (HttpConnection) connectionDescriptor.getConnection();
    }

    return connection;
}


public boolean parseData()
{   
    InputStream  is = getInputStream("http://data.****.com/getData.aspx");
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
    Document doc;
    try 
    {
        docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
        is.close();
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        docBuilder.isValidating();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {           
        return false;
    }                                   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try with connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(12000); add a bigger time to get the responses.

Comment: thanks for your comment.I tried with connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(20000); but it never worked for me.Actually now this scenario happens , When i navigate from first screen to second screen and came back to first screen and when i again go to second screen the connection is getting lost.

Comment: i haven't closed the inputsream thats why the issue happened edited my question.